# How to specify port number using mysql-connector-python (error 2003)

Tags: python, mysql, ssh, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to connect via SSH to a MySQL server from my local Windows machine. The SSH connection works fine, but I am unable to connect to the MySQL server when running the following Python script:

```
import mysql.connector
import sys
import time
import paramiko

host = 'remote-ssh-host'
i = 1

while True:
    print("Trying to connect to %s (%i/30)" % (host, i))

    try:
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(host, port=22, username='sshuser', password='sshpwd')
        print("Connected to %s" % host)
        break
    except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
        print("Authentication failed when connecting to %s" % host)
        sys.exit(1)
    except:
        print("Could not SSH to %s, waiting for it to start" % host)
        i += 1
        time.sleep(2)

    # If we could not connect within time limit
    if i == 30:
        print("Could not connect to %s. Giving up" % host)
        sys.exit(1)



cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user="mysqluser", password="mysqlpwd",
                              host="mysqlhost",
                              port=3307)
```

Here is the output:

```
Trying to connect to remote-ssh-host (1/30)
Connected to remote-ssh-host

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 469, in open_connection
    self.sock.connect(sockaddr)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\path\to\script\ssh_mysql_test.py", line 50, in <module>
    port="3307"
...
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 472, in open_connection
    errno=2003, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysqlhost:3307' (10060)
```

Similar questions have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30188796/connecting-to-mysql-database-via-ssh) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17179905/python-code-to-establish-an-ssh-to-remote-server-and-then-connect-to-mysql), but I think this problem has to do with the way mysql-connector-python handles the connection string for the port number, because when using the Putty terminal I can make it work:

```
login as: sshuser
sshuser@remote-ssh-host's password:
sshuser@remote-ssh-host:~$ mysql -h mysqlhost -P 3307 -u mysqluser -p
Enter password:
...
mysql>
```

But, when specifying the port number in the same way as e.g. the mysql-connector-python does:

```
login as: sshuser
sshuser@remote-ssh-host's password:
sshuser@remote-ssh-host:~$ mysql -h mysqlhost:3307 -u mysqluser -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'mysqlhost:3307' (0)
```

I realize the error numbers are different (2003 vs. 2005), but I think that they are related. So the question actually is: How can I format the port number in such a way that the connection executes as `-h hostname -P port` instead of `-h hostname:port`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your ssh and MySQL connections are completely separated. In order for your MySQL connection to work through ssh, you need to **tunnel** the MySQL connection through the ssh one.

The [first SO topic you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30188796/connecting-to-mysql-database-via-ssh) actually provides the answer to this problem: uses an ssh tunnelling component to create the tunnel and the MySQL connection is directed through the tunnel.

```
server =  SSHTunnelForwarder(
     ('host', 22),
     ssh_password="password",
     ssh_username="username",
     remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306))
```

The above code binds the ssh connection to port 3306 of the localhost. So any connection made to 127.0.0.1:3306 will be tunnelled through the ssh connection to the remote server.

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://user:pass@127.0.0.1:%s/db' % server.local_bind_port)
```

In the above code the MySQL connection is made to 127.0.0.1:3306, therefore it will be tunnelled though the ssh connection. You need to follow the same pattern: create an ssh tunnel bound to a local port and in your MySQL connection string specify this local port instead of the remote one.